# Convert from days to milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime-conversion

I want to create a function that will convert the days into milliseconds. The days format is stored as 0.2444, so how to convert this to milliseonds?

Comment: How many hours in a day? How many minutes in an hour? How many seconds in a minute? How many milliseconds in a second?

Comment: `0.2444` what does it signifies ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi it probably means .2444 of a day aka 24.44% or 5.86 hours.

Comment: Oh and don't forget that some days are 25h, some 23h, and some even 23h59min59sec (leap second).

Comment: @giraff - I think you have to ignore that got the question to make sense.  The is .244 of a generic day, not a specific day.

Comment: @Stephen: I slightly disagree: it depends on how it is used. If it is added to a specific day, then 0.5 days may not be 12 hours.

Comment: @giraff - a function that converts a fraction of a specific day to milliseconds has to take two arguments, or an implicit argument (like "today").  I have difficulty believing that it is what the OP's application really needs.  (For example, nobody in their right mind would require a user to enter a fraction of a day into a timesheet **taking account of the number of hours in the specific day**.  Now we don't **know** that's what the OP's application is, but ...)

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for brightening my day.  Lawyers typically charge in 6-minute increments.  But I've always wanted a contract where I can fill in my timesheet then charge by the millisecond.

Comment: There are actually 86400002 milliseconds in a day, if your app is going to be independent upon updating it's time (no internet service/no sim card on old phone for examples) for extended periods of time those 2 milliseconds add up noticably over even a few hours.

Answer (score 320):

The best practice for this, in my opinion is:

```
TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);     // 1 day to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(23); // 23 minutes to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(4);    // 4 hours to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(96); // 96 seconds to milliseconds.
```

Comment: No, this should not be accepted answer , because DAYS.toMillis takes only long argument and OP has days in double

Comment: this answer is the answer most people who come here are looking for, but not the answer to OP

Comment: Not a best practice. It's easy way

Answer (score 126):

In addition to the other answers, there is also the [TimeUnit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class which allows you to convert one time duration to another. For example, to find out how many milliseconds make up one day:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS); //gives 86400000
```

Note that this method takes a `long`, so if you have a fraction of a day, you will have to multiply it by the number of milliseconds in one day.

Answer (score 25):

Won't `days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` suffice?

Comment: He probably wants it as a long, so you might need to round it from a double at the end too.

Answer (score 14):

24 hours = 86400 seconds = 86400000 milliseconds. Just multiply your number with 86400000.

Answer (score 12):

Its important to mention that once in 4-5 years this method might give a 1 second error, becase of a leap-second (http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/leapseconds.cfm), and the correct formula for that day would be

```
(24*60*60 + 1) * 1000
```

There is a question [Are leap seconds catered for by Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065355/are-leap-seconds-catered-for-by-calendar) and the answer is no.

So, if You're designing super time-dependant software, be careful about this formula.

Comment: Just if someone is interested — there is going to be a leap second in 2016

Answer (score 4):

You can use this utility class -

```
public class DateUtils
{
    public static final long SECOND_IN_MILLIS = 1000;
    public static final long MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 60;
    public static final long HOUR_IN_MILLIS = MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 60;
    public static final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = HOUR_IN_MILLIS * 24;
    public static final long WEEK_IN_MILLIS = DAY_IN_MILLIS * 7;
}
```

If you are working on **Android framework** then just `import` it *(also named `DateUtils`)* under `package android.text.format`

Answer (score 3):

```
public static double toMilliSeconds(double day)
{
    return day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

or as `long`:

```
public static long toMilliSeconds(double day)
{
    return (long) (day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int day = 5;
long dayInMilliseconds = day * org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY
```

Comment: it's always better to explain what your answer means. Please take few minutes to illustrate how this code works