# Java regex for yyyymmddhhmmss

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a Java regex pattern for **yyyymmddhhmmss** format. It should also check for the leap years.

Below is the pattern which checks only yyyymmdd and leap year but now I need to extend it to yyyymmddhhmmss (so that it includes 24-hour time format validation).

```
 public static boolean isValidFormat(String format) {
    String pattern = "(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))$";
    boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, format);  
    return matches;
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do it using regular expressions? It is much more simplier to use `SimpleDateFormat.parse`.

Comment: I have solved with `dd-mm-yyyy`  format. you may try this and convert your date after check. demo  https://regex101.com/r/tR0yC5/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-regex way to validate datetime values.

```
import java.text.*;
...
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
sdf.setLenient(false);
try {
       Date dt2 = sdf.parse("20150229105950");
       System.out.println(dt2);
}
catch (Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("NOT VALID");
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rqBwL9)

In order to also validate 24-hour time *with your regex*, you need to append this to it:

```
(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}
```

The `(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])` part will validate numbers from `00` to `23` and `(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}` will validate minutes and seconds.

Then, your regex will look like:

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gN1eD8/1)

Note you are using `matches()` method that forces a match on the *whole* string, so it seems the `$` anchor is not necessary.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. If you find my answer helpful, please consider also upvoting. Are you sure you do not need a code example with `SimpleDateFormat`? I can provide it as well.

Comment: You should have suggested SimpleDateFormat in the first place. Anyway, I have written an answer with SimpleDateFormat example.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Again you are telling people what to use. Please respect the freedom of choice.

Comment: Between an approach which is hardly maintainable, and an approach which has been thoroughly tested provided by the API and simple to use, of course, I would recommend the simple approach to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to deal with leap second (which [is not supported in Sun/Oracle JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4272347)), use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with [`setLenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-) to `false` to disable lenient parsing. This is better than writing an unmaintainable regex to parse it.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SO31132861 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        df.setLenient(false);

        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160630231110"));
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228231100"));
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231100"));

        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "21000229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2100
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160631231110")); // 31st Jun invalid day
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231160")); // Second > 59
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2015
        System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228241100")); // Hour > 23
    }

    private static Date tryParse(DateFormat df, String s) {
        try {
            return df.parse(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need leap second, you might want to take a look at this answer: [Are leap seconds catered for by Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065355/are-leap-seconds-catered-for-by-calendar/17140501#17140501)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## No need for regex

Java has an industry-leading set of classes for date-time handling, found in the *java.time* package. Let them handle parsing of your input strings rather than messing with regex.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`).

Define a formatting pattern to match your input strings.

```
String input = "20180123123456" ;  // yyyymmddhhmmss
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
```

[Parse as a `LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) because your input lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56

To trap for invalid input, catch [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
String input = "20180123123456" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = null;
try {
    ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR - invalid input for date-time. input: " + input ) ;
    e.printStackTrace();  // Handle invalid input.
}
```

By the way, be aware that without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, your input string and the `LocalDateTime` do *not* represent a specific moment, and are *not* a point on the timeline. They represent *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the min/max range of time zone offsets).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

Spent some time elaborating it, but it's pretty much straightforward:

```
(\d{4}(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])(([0-5][0-9]){2}))
```

I think this is what you're looking for. You can test it in [regexr](http://www.regexr.com)

Cheers!