# Regexp for a timestamp with this format YYYYmmddHHMMSS

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that has a set of timestamps and I look for a way to filter them and find the wrong formatted from the well formatted by using a regex expression :

```
$line = array(20171203124500,20150120183045,20140621064431);
$args = array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
              'options' => array('regexp' => 'REGEX-HERE'), );
$result = filter_var_array($line, $args);
var_dump($result);
```

I also want to check if the day of the month is correct :

- the date 31 April should not match
- the date 29/02/2003 should not match and 29/02/2004 should.

I have this expression :

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:(?:(?:31\/0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:29\/0?2\/(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$
```

But it is given for dates with this format :  31/01/2001

> This expression validates dates in the Brazilian d/m/y format (from
>   1/1/1600 - 12/31/9999). The days are validated for the given month and
>   year. Leap years are validated for all 4 digits years from 1600-9999.
>   Days and months must be 1 or 2 digits and may have leading zeros.
>   Years must be 4 digit years, between 1600 and 9999. Date separator
>   must be a slash (/)

How to adapt this regexp to match the format I look for : YYYYmmddHHMMSS

Comment: Just exchange day and year part.

Comment: @Toto the question is not duplicate, the one you mentioned is not at all what I'm looking for

Comment: @JavaQueen: The regex is taken from [my old Java answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31133075/3832970) without any reference to that. I would not give any rep points to Rarasen for that. I would delete this post altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be :

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}
```

To know if a date is valid, you need to use `checkdate($month, $day, $year)`.

See doc: [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Comment: Aweseom! that works very perfectly. Thank you. @Rarasen

Comment: @JavaQueen: Does it really work? You mentioned `20000229` should not be valid and it is valid with the regex above. See https://regex101.com/r/pIW9DU/1

Comment: You can't validate a date with a regex. You need to double check it : first the structure with regex, then date valid date with checkdate.

Comment: Yes it works properly. 20000229 is correct. I edited the question 20030229 should not and 20040229 should.

Comment: @Rarasen I'll use both methods

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex is not working because it's too long, even when using delimiters. wrong strings match

Comment: Yes, because you are using a Java regex that *was used with `String#matches()`*  in PHP `preg_match`. `^` and `$` must be added.